# Estimating camera height, orientation and field of view from a single image

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction (or let me know if I'm on the right path).

I am trying to build an image editing application that uses computer vision to assist with virtual object insertion - Basically AR but with the constraint of a single monocular image (uncalibrated).

The virtual object insertion will only occur on the ground plane (eg think of a virtual rug on the floor). Because of this (much like AR) I will need to align a virtual camera with the physical camera and composite the rendered virtual scene with the physical image.

I have had success training a semantic segmentation deep CNN to predict the flooring of an indoor scene (which serves as a mask, so that the virtual object, eg rug, is only visible in this area), but I am running into difficulties determining the camera properties.

My intuition is that in order to build a virtual scene that can be composited, the camera calibration properties that I care about is the height of the camera, the pitch, the roll and the field of view (or focal length). Now because this is just for rendering purposes, the estimated values don't need to be super accurate, just close enough that a rendered object doesn't look distorted.

After researching the problem I have come across this paper [Single View Metrology In the Wild](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.09529.pdf) - It appears to provide an estimate for all of the calibration properties as listed above. With that said, with no training code available, this may end up taking quite a long time for something that may or may not work - although one I am willing to investigate if this is the only option.

Am I missing an obvious approach here? I've read some papers around more traditional CV approaches (eg vanishing points) and some more modern approaches (eg UprightNet), but they usually are missing one of the necessary camera calibration values listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get camera parameters by calibrating it according to [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Eh, "more modern"... [Canoma](http://www.canoma.com/) was released in 1998 IIRC, and was based in part on work done earlier by Paul Devevec at UCB. Both showed that realistic CG insertion on single image was doable with very little/easy user input.

The software calibrated the camera's focal length and pose by having the user trace with the mouse a few boxes or cylinders matching structures in view (e.g. buildings, towers). With a little practice, one or two boxes were all that was needed to get a good solution.